# Wordpress page as subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web

I do not want to redirect the page to a subdomain:

```
http://example.com/page -> http://page.example.com
```

I want to completely move the `page` to a subdomain.
This plugin looks good https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/page-as-subdomain-lite/
I'd rather welcome the way through .htaccess

Comment: so you are using apache for web server, are you on a shared host or a dedicated one?

Comment: @mur shared hosting

Comment: I am assuming you have DNS cname setup properly, in apache you can achieve this using Virtual Host but i am not sure to what extent in shared servers you will be allowed to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hosting-> Subdomain-> create a subdomain -> go to file manager in the autogenerated folder somewhat page.example.com -> paste / upload your files there

- create a new database
- import sql
- change url structure through wp-options in table
- change config as per the new database, that's it!

Comment: I dont want new Wordpress site on subdomain. I want to have one existing Wordpress page on the subdomain with same name. `http://example.com/page to http://page.example.com`